# Comparing result, input and output of tests in shell

Tags: bash, shell

Basically what I want to do is write a **shellscript that will run series of test, take in any input (if there is any) and compare the test result with an output.**

So my file looks something like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Let's set our working directory
DIR="./tests"

# And create some variables
passed=0
failed=0
totalamount=0
returned=0

# Inform the user about start of testing
echo "========= TESTING INITIALIZED ========="

# Actual testing I'm trying to do
```

So I assume first thing I should do is create a loop that will run through the tests

```
for file in "./tests/1/*.test do
```

So Now I'm unsure how can I compare the output of my .test file with a prepared .output program.

For example, I have a program test1.test, that will calculate 2+3. The result is 5. What I want is to have this value stored and compare it with my test1.output

Any idea how to do this?

In the end I'll just compare the two values

```
if [ $returned -eq $expected ]; then
   echo "Test was succesful"
else
   echo "Test was unsuccesful"
fi
```

Basically the end result should look something like:

```
Test: test1.test  
    Expected result: X  
    Your result: Y  
    Test was succesful/unsuccesful
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `diff` to compare the test result with the output expected. If they match, then you could assume the test was successful. For example:

```
test1check="$(diff /folder/test1 /folder/test1-expected)"
if [ -z "$test1check" ]; then
   echo "Test was succesful"
else
   echo "Test was unsuccesful, difference on results: $test1check"
fi
```

If the user is going to make inputs, or in other cases at your discretion, you could run the same comparison but ignore case differences (ex: "APPLE" would match "apple"), by changing the first line like this:

```
test1check="$(diff -i /folder/test1 /folder/test1-expected)"
```

One more thing: keep in mind that this code is sensitive to newlines, so if the test result does not end in a new line and the expected result does, the script will point out the difference.